# What counts as a trap for the Party Hard achievement 'Engineer'?

Tags: achievements, party-hard

I'm trying to earn 'Engineer', which is to pass a level 3 times without using traps:

[image: Engineer achievement on Steam]

However, despite not activating a trap, I haven't made any progress in this achievement. The only reason I can think of is that something else I'm doing is counting as a 'trap', and therefore triggering the achievement detection.

Does picking up/using items, disposing of bodies (dumpster, ice box etc), or taking shortcuts (windows, ladders etc) count as 'traps' for the purposes of this achievement?

If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, disposing of bodies and using shortcuts counts as a trap as far as the achievement is concerned. You'll just have to deal with taking your time on this one.
It's easier to get it on the first level where things aren't as frantic and you can just pick off people fairly unnoticed.

Comment: Does picking up / using items also count?

Comment: No, I don't believe they do.

Answer (score 2):

Its really easy if you can finish the game and unlock the police man, as he can carry bodies without suspicion. Just pick them off while their alone and carry the body to a hiding spot (a good one being that corner on the outside of the building beside the bathroom. DGarvanski is right about both the map and that the disposing of bodies is counted as a trap, but the short cuts aren't and the police man character can't use traps anyway.